# replace string in java using string builder

Tags: java, regex, stringbuilder

I have a String in java :

```
String str = "150,def,ghi,jkl";
```

I want to get sub string till first comma, do some manipulations on it and then replace it by modified string.

My code :

```
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(str);

String[] temp = str.split(",");
String newVal = Integer.parseInt(temp[0])*10+"";

int i=0;
for(i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
  if(str.charAt(i)==',') break;
}

sBuilder.replace(0, i, newVal);
```

What is the best way to do this because I am working on big data this code will be called millions of times, I am wondering if there is possibility of avoiding for loop.

Comment: What is wrong with for loops?

Comment: I am not sure but calling loop so many time might effect time performance, so i was thinking if there are some methods on string to achieve this.

Comment: *"might effect time performance"* - profile it. Optimize once you see that it causes a problem.

Comment: I agree to w4rumy comment. Please measure first and keep in mind that the JIT compiler improves code that is often used. JIT also compiles some bytecode to native code to improve performance. Therefore you should use the "normal" java methods like String.replace or indexOf, because they are very very often used and therefore compiled by JIT first.

Comment: yes indexOf is what i need. Thnx

Comment: don't use `StringBuilder`..

Answer (score 3):

You also can use the method `replace()` of String Object itself.

```
String str = "150,def,ghi,jkl";
String[] temp = str.split(",");
String newVal = Integer.parseInt(temp[0])*10+"";

String newstr = newVal + str.substring(str.indexOf(","),str.length());
```

Comment: Also instead of `split(",")` that will each time create and use regex Pattern, we can simply use `str.substring(0,str.indexOf(","))` to get first part of string. BTW to get second part we can simply use `str.substring(str.indexOf(","))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str = "150,def,ghi,jkl";
    String newVal = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0,str.indexOf(",")))*10+"";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should at least avoid excessive String concatenation and regular expressions.

```
String prefix = sBuilder.substring(0, sBuilder.indexOf(","));
String newVal = ...;
sBuilder.replace(0, newVal.length(), newVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't now if this is useful to you but we often use :

```
org.springframework.util.StringUtils
```

In the StringUtils class you have alot of useful methods for comma seperated files.